# Git : Find all remote branches eligible* for deletion (* last commit is a merge to master )

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I know this question has been broached already in a similar vein . However I'm looking for a stricter eligibility criterion viz . I'm interested only in branches which

1. have been merged to master
2. have no further commits after the merge
   to master

This is to avoid deleting branches which have some further ( possibly valuable ) work but which have not been merged up to master ( through possible omission , abandoned pull request etc. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much simpler, for this particular case (checking what remote-tracking branches are fully merged into `master`):

```
git branch -r --merged master
```

(and of course `--no-merged` for ones that may still need work on them, as per comments on the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36798334/1256452)).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proposed solution:

Assumption : The oldest ancestor is assumed to be origin/master . This is standard practice but no harm to call it out .

```
git branch -r --list --contains `git rev-list  --max-parents=0 origin/master`| grep -v origin\/master | sed 's/^..\(.*\)/\1/' | xargs -I {}  sh -c "echo -n {}' : '; git log --graph -n 1 {} | grep -c '^|[\]\ \ Merge'"
```

Step by Step

1. Find all remote branches which have the initial master commit as a
   descendant .
2. For each branch check that the latest commit is a merge back to oldest ancestor.

The output report looks like the following  . A 1 alongside the branch means it is eligible to delete

```
origin/0.2016.02-release : 1
origin/0.2016.03-release : 1
origin/Fix-for-NPE-schedule-master : 0
origin/Fix-possible-infinite-loop-master : 0
origin/Fixing-unit-tests-master : 0
origin/NoBodyRequiredForActivity-master : 0
origin/Removing-not-needed-dependency-master : 0
origin/updateDevServiceConfig-master : 0
origin/updateServerPort-master : 0
origin/updatedPom : 1
```

Hope this helps anyone looking for something similar . Would welcome any suggestions and improvements

Comment: You need not worry about root commits (`--max-parents=0`), only about each tipmost commit.  Any merge causes all the merged-in commits to be reachable from that path, and all predecessors are reachable from their successors by definition.  The `--merged` predicate of `git branch` (now available in `git for-each-ref` as well) handles this for you, so `git branch -r --merged master` gets you your list.

Comment: but isn't it true that `git branch -r --merged master` won't distinguish between branches that have further commits after the latest merge to master and those that don't ? That is the problem I am interested in .

Comment: No, it is not true: `--merged` means "test the tip commit of `$theirs` against the tip commit of `$ours`, with the obvious meaning for `$ours` and `$theirs`, and the test consisting of "is ancestor" (the same test performed by `git merge-base --is-ancestor`).  Suppose, for instance, that `origin/good` points to commit `X` and `origin/bad` points to commit `Y`, where `X` is either behind the tip of `master` or is the tip of `master`, but `Y` is not reachable from (the tip of) `master`.  The `--is-ancestor` test passes for `X` (`X` *is* an ancestor of the tip of `master`) but fails for `Y`.

Comment: It's worth noting one other thing: all of these tests (yours and mine both) assume that whatever result you just got for `origin/foo` is still valid.  It's possible that between the time you test it, and the time you send a delete request, someone else has updated `origin/foo` to change the result.  I have not yet tested whether the `--force-with-lease` option works with `--delete`, but this is the kind of thing one might want to use when doing these deletions.

Comment: Thank you Torek I have verified that what you have said is indeed correct . Your second point is also germaine in that it has reminded me that the real point of the question is to first identify the branches that we don’t want to delete because we need to see what extra code is in there that hasn’t yet been merged to master . With this in mind we can use the complementary command 
`git branch -r --list --no-merged master`
to list the branches whose code we need to curate .  Feel free to provide an answer that I may mark it as the accepted answer . Otherwise I can edit the answer above.